# How can I have a file appearing on a WebDav server trigger a BizTalk event?

Tags: biztalk, webdav, biztalk-2010

I have a legacy system which can create files visible in WebDav as an output. I'd like to trigger a BizTalk orchestration receive port when a file matching a filter appears - so a lot like the standard File adapter, but for WebDav.

I found the [BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter](http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/), which can pull in a file by HTTP, but it looks abandoned, poorly documented, and out of date.

So, how is it done? Can I use the standard HTTP adapter perhaps?

Comment: Not sure I'd agree that the Scheduled Task Adapter is abandoned ... there are versions for 2006 R2, 2009 and 2010. And there is a nice starter at ... http://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/biztalk-scheduled-task-adapter-4-0-introduction-and-installation-process/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had to go with a workaround on this where we made a completely unrelated separate process to make a copy of the file from the legacy system appear in a Samba share, which we in turn attach to with an ordinary FILE adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able access the WebDAV via a UNC path from the BizTalk server the File Adapter *should* do the trick.

Comment: Tried that on a local instance and could not get it to work. The FILE adapter explicitely checks for ACL permissions, that a WebDAV network share does not exhibit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to assign a drive letter to the WebDav folder?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Comment: This looks like it could perhaps be a promising approach, but I haven't gotten it working on Win7 yet. @Maxime-Labelle or Fabio, do you know if this avoids the ACL permissions issue?

Comment: After several attempts, I have been unable to get the WebDav folder assigned to a drive letter in Win 7 64 bit.